# Wouldn't adding DevExpress Nuget authorization key in nuget.config of an OSS .sln project expose the key?

Tags: nuget, devexpress, blazor, github-actions

I'm experimenting with the DevExpress.Blazor Controls. Also I like to get my CICD workflow going right from getgo so that any issues crop up sooner rather than later. Since the project is OSS hosted on Github we will be using GitHub actions

To install the DevExpress.Blazor control, I need to add a unique  URL as my Nuget Feed

While there is a DevExpress link [https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/400604/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages/integrate-nuget-to-popular-continuous-integration-systems] that lists how to configure various CICD unfortunately Github actions is missing out. The closest approximation is Azure DevOps but it mentions to tag the Nuget Feed in an unencrypted Nuget.config file. This would expose my Authorization Key. Is there any recommended way to ensure this is done in a secure manner?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to store the auth key in the NuGet.config file (i.e., in the repository), it is possible to [hide unique NuGet feed in Azure DevOps Build pipeline](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T818634/devexpress-nuget-how-to-hide-unique-nuget-feed-in-azure-devops-build-pipeline)